# Replacing a word in String only when it is with a digit. C#

Tags: c#

I have a string and I am looking a way to replace `EUR` with `€` but only when `EUR` is written together with an `int`. 
E.g.

```
string str = "EUR is einen groß geld 10EUR";
```

becomes

```
   str = "EUR ist einen groß geld 10€"
```

Comment: I recommend learning Regex for these things

Comment: I recommend not relying on Regex and string-processing too much.

Comment: Btw: Those phrases are grammatically incorrect and make no sense, in case it matters. And please tell a bit about your situation. What are the possible inputs? Why do you want to grind those string at runtime? You lose a lot of knowledge potential from this question at the moment.

Comment: @phresnel I put just an example. The string I will work with might be quiet different then this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allthough *[Regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)* is probably the way to go here, relying on it sistematically can dull your *skills* when dealing with these kind of situations.

It is always fun (if you have the time) to try and solve the problem with good old string iteration :). The following code should do the work (haven't tested it extensively) and it might be more instructive than using a *Regex* pattern string you probably don't even understand (you wouldn't be asking this question if you did).

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static string SubstituteCurrencyString(this string input, string currencyString, string currencySymbol, bool onlyWhenPrecededByDigits = true)
    {
        if (input == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("input");

        if (currencyString == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("currencyString");

        if (currencySymbol == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("currencySymbol");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
            return input;

        if (!onlyWhenPrecededByDigits)
            return input.Replace(currencyString, currencySymbol);

        bool parsingNumber = false;
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(input.Length);

        using (var stringEnumerator = input.GetEnumerator())
        {
            int index = -1;

            while (stringEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                ++index;

                if (char.IsDigit(stringEnumerator.Current))
                {
                    parsingNumber = true;
                }
                else if (stringEnumerator.Current == CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator[0])
                {
                    //Do nothing. If we are "parsing" a number, we keep on "parsing" a number. If were not, we are not.
                }
                else if (stringEnumerator.Current == CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator[0])
                {
                    //Do nothing. If we are "parsing" a number, we keep on "parsing" a number. If were not, we are not.
                }
                else
                {
                    if (parsingNumber && checkCurrencyString(input, currencyString, index))
                    {
                        b.Append(currencySymbol);

                        for (int i = 0; i < currencyString.Length; ++i)
                        {
                            stringEnumerator.MoveNext();
                            ++index;
                        }
                    }

                    parsingNumber = false;
                }

                if (index < input.Length)
                {
                    b.Append(stringEnumerator.Current);
                }
            }
        }

        return b.ToString();
    }

    private static bool checkCurrencyString(string input, string currencyString, int index)
    {
        Debug.Assert(input != null);
        Debug.Assert(currencyString != null);
        Debug.Assert(0 < index && index < input.Length);

        if (input.Length - index < currencyString.Length)
            return false;

        var potentialCurrenyString = input.Substring(index, currencyString.Length);
        return string.Compare(potentialCurrenyString, currencyString, false) == 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this, I've taken couple of EURs here

Code

```
string str = "EUR is einen groß 90EUR geld 10EUR";
var pattern = @"(\d+)(EUR)";
var replaced = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, pattern, "$1€");
```

here is the result
`replaced = "EUR is einen groß 90€ geld 10€"`

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+(?<toreplace>EUR)");
```

This regex will match the scenario you've described. I'll leave the replacement as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do that more generic. Have a dictionary with currency as key and symbol as value.
And with RegEx do replace the currency followed by digits with the value in the dictionary

Comment: Whew. Now we have two, ..., wait, THREE problems.